# how get a file path by uri which authority is "com.android.externalstorage.documents"

Tags: android

I want to get a file path through open a file choose by startActivityForResult which intent is Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT and setType(* / *), but when I choose open form the "Nexus 5X" item the return uri is "com.android.externalstorage.documents"， how to handle this type uri.
There are some codes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_OK, true);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_ADD_ACTION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjZIY.jpg)

Comment: That is not the complete 'return uri'.

Comment: one of the complete uri is "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/home%3Ademo_decry.mp4"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

External Storage URIs are of the following form:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/root%3Apath
```

where `root` is the root of the storage medium, `%3A` is simply an escaped colon and `path` is the filesystem path relative to the root (also escaped).

On devices with emulated primary storage (i.e. modern Android devices), the root for primary storage (i.e. `/sdcard`) is usually called `primary`. In other cases it seems to be the media ID (4+4 hex digits separated by a hyphen).

You can also try using this (requires API 21 for full functionality):

```
 public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String filePath = "";

    // ExternalStorageProvider
    String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    String[] split = docId.split(':');
    String type = split[0];

    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            //getExternalMediaDirs() added in API 21
            File[] external = context.getExternalMediaDirs();
            if (external.length > 1) {
                filePath = external[1].getAbsolutePath();
                filePath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.indexOf("Android")) + split[1];
            }
        } else {
            filePath = "/storage/" + type + "/" + split[1];
        }
        return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: I’ve edited the answer, adding an introduction and dropping irrelevant (to the question) portions of the code.

Answer (score 0):

> how to handle this type uri

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.